# Is PHP-GTK widely used?

Tags: php, gui

Is PHP-GTK widely used for desktop application? Is it recommended to use?  Is there a big company who uses PHP GTK?

Comment: The language is plain old PHP. It just as an extra library (and is presumably not hooked up to a web server).

Comment: Define "widely".

Comment: @S.Lott: doesn't matter, it's not widely used with **any** definition of "widely".

Comment: @vartec: While that may be true, it doesn't improve the question, does it?

Answer (score 6):

**No, it is not.** Quite the opposite, it's practically a dead project. There was almost no activity for 3½ years now. It had never really got any traction, as PHP is very much web oriented, and there was not much interest in GUI library for it.

Comment: thanks man! now it is clear for me that PHP-GTK is not recommended language anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I've only seen it used in academic settings as an exercise in 'what not to do'.

With regard to scripting language GUIs the industry appears to be heading pretty heavily towards Python and it's subsequent libraries like PyQT and PyGTK.  They're much easier to use, much better supported and much more proliferant than PHP.

Comment: Plus they are probably much more readable. PHP-GTK made my eyes bleed